# Run Command If Player Is Not Within Radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a repeating command block that will run a command if a player is not within the set radius, but I don't know how. If anybody knows please help. I am running 1.16.5

Answer (score 2):

```
execute unless @a[distance=..10] run say There is no player within a 10 block spherical radius
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: @JeremyEarlBulmer if it worked you can show others this by clicking the grey checkmark to mark it as accepted. This both rewards the answerer and marks it as accepted so others know for sure it works.